# Add and remove element on click with fadetoggle?

Tags: jquery, append, removechild

I have this kind od function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('footer').each(function() {
        $(this).parent().append('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    });
});
$("[data-action]").click(function(data) {
    var link = $(this).attr('data-action');
    $("#overlay").fadeToggle();
    $.get(link, function(data) {
        $("#navigation-control").empty().append(data);
    });

});
```

That adds #overlay to footer parent, the problem is that ppend only goes on Document ready.
What i need is to append and remove #overlay in click function, i dont want that element to always be on page, but i have problem where in function to call it and where to remove it on toggle??

Something like this

```
$("[data-action]").click(function(data) {
    var link = $(this).attr('data-action');
    $('footer').parent().append('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    $("#overlay").fadeToggle();
    $.get(link, function(data) {
        $("#navigation-control").empty().append(data);
    });
   $('#overlay').remove();
});
```

But i want to keep overlay there only on second click to remove? This way overlay does not show at all, because it is append and remove??

Answer (score 0):

Try to use setTimeout like,

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#overlay').remove();
},1000); // for 1 second delay
```

Or you can use fadeOut then remove like,

```
$('#overlay').fadeOut(1000).remove(); // with effects
```

Full code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('footer').each(function() {
        $(this).parent().append('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    });    
    $("[data-action]").click(function(data) {
        var link = $(this).attr('data-action');
        $('footer').parent().append('<div id="overlay"></div>');
        $.get(link, function(data) {
            $("#navigation-control").empty().append(data);
            $('#overlay').fadeOut(1000).remove(); // after performing your data
        });       
    });
});
```